# curl:unresolved host. i have this error when i try to connect to nginx server

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to connect to an Nginx server with Minikube, through a NodePort-type service, running on Amazon Linux 2, to obtain the Nginx server welcome page.  But when I try to I have this error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-8-201 ~]# minikube ip
! Executing "docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}" took an unusually long time: 2.137525008s
* Restarting the docker service may improve performance.
192.168.49.2
[root@ip-172-31-8-201 ~]# curl 192.168.49.2:30123
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 30123: Connection refused
```

I have a file `svcNodeport.yaml` whcih consists of this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30123
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

I have a file pod.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
 - image: nginx
   name: nginx
 ports:
   - containerPort: 8080
     protocol: TCP
```

svc.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

last file pod4svc.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Doesn't nginx run on port 80 by default? You didn't mention nginx config so I will let myself assume you didn't change anything. So unless you changed sth use `targetPort: 80` and let me know if this helped.

Comment: I have changed the target port to 30123

Comment: What? Why? Target port has to be set to the port you application is listening on.

Comment: I need to use the port 30123